# Moved into flat, cold water tank leaking, can it be removed?

Tags: plumbing, water, heating, water-heater

Background
I've moved into a flat recently and have been renovating. I'm doing all the work myself - have installed a new bathroom, new kitchen, new shower and cistern etc. and now I've realised the cold water tank is perished and beginning to leak.

[image: The offending tank, around 280L but with about 240L of water in it.]

[image: A slow drip leak that has started recently]

The plumbing cupboard is a complete mess, it seems as if there have been about 4 different generations of plumber with each taking the easiest and quickest route to do what they want, and ignoring any future hassle this might cause.

[image: Plumbing cupboard]

For reference, we don't have a boiler in the flat, other than the immersion boiler shown in the picture below. The cold and hot water directly coming into the flat are what we use.

Is it OK to remove the cold water tank entirely? I see the hot water vent is going into the tank, but as we never use the immersion boiler and don't have any other type of boiler, is it safe to simply route that into the drain?

I would be keen to remove this ticking liability.

Comment: The most common reason for a cold water tank is that the main water supply has too low pressure or has flow problems so that it can't reliably supply the need.  Are this issues still a problem?  It's possible that the service has improved since this system was installed.  Otherwise, you'll still want a tank but this one has outlived its usefulness.  Either replace it or hire a plumber to replace it.

Comment: When I switch the mains water coming into the flat off from the stop valve in the flat, no taps function, so I'm assuming the tank is superfluous

Comment: Not necessarily superfluous.  The mains supply fills the tank, which is then used as a buffer to supply the water in your flat.  You could try bypassing it and see if you're satisfied with what the main supply offers without the tank.

Comment: I emptied the cold water tank briefly, and even though our hot water is supplied communally, the cold water tank emptying results in no hot water. It's confusing, as the boiler is downstairs and is common to all the flats in our 16-storey building.